# Output corresponding elements of two different arrays in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have two different arrays. First contains the name of people and second some information about them. I want to sort the first one on the basis of name and then output the the names. At the same time, I also want to output the description of corresponding name from other array.

I would have used associative arrays but two people can have same names.

Could anyone please explain, how can I get the element from second array at corresponding location as output?

```
asort($names);
$n_index = 0;
foreach($names as $name) {
    echo $name.' '.$descrption[$n_index].'\n';
    $n_index++;
}
```

I can't use `array_search` because the keys or names are not unique. :)

Here is some sample data:

```
$names = ['Andy', 'Mandy', 'Andy', 'Alex', 'Megan', 'Mandy', 'Megan'];
$description = ['Tall', 'Short', 'Slim', 'Short', 'Tall', 'Fat', 'Tall'];
```

Output:

```
Alex Short
Andy Tall
Andy Slim
Mandy Short
Mandy Fat
Megan Tall
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you show the sample of arrays you are using?

Comment: Seeing some sample data and expected output would make this a lot clearer - thanks

Comment: @LovepreetSingh I have added the expect output along with sample data.

Comment: @ADyson I have added the data. :)

Comment: Your description of the problem suggests you've decided the sorting has to happen before the combining of the data. It doesn't. Combine the data, while the array indexes still correspond to each other, and _then_ sort. Much easier.

Comment: @ADyson I wasn't sure how to approach the problem. :) @Deceze used `array_map` but I would have been stuck at using associate arrays to store data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a sensible data structure that keeps both kinds of information together, sort that, and output it:

```
$people = array_map(null, $names, $description);
// $people = [['Andy', 'Tall'], ['Mandy', 'Short'], ...]
usort($people, function ($a, $b) { return strcmp($a[0], $b[0]); });

foreach ($people as $person) {
    echo $person[0], ' ', $person[1], PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Deceze. :) I forgot to mention one thing in the question. There can be duplicates such that 'Mandy` and `Tall` occur twice or thrice. How can I make sure that only unique combinations are echoed?

Comment: Only unique *combinations*? Make an array of strings you want to output (`['Andy Tall', 'Mandy Short', ...]`), and put it through `array_unique`.

Comment: Thanks @Deceze. You are a genius. :) It is amazing how quickly you solved my problem. :D